# Mocking / Fake / Replacing hardware dependent functions in Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, go, raspberry-pi

I have currently the following function in one file:

```go
func pinExported(pin int) bool {
    pinPath := fmt.Sprintf("/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d", pin)
    if file, err := os.Stat(pinPath); err == nil && len(file.Name()) > 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

and another code part in the same file which uses the above function which looks like this:

```go
func isGpioPinExported(gpioPin int) bool {
    exported := pinExported(gpioPin)
    for !exported && (timeOut < timeOutForPinExportInMilliseconds) {
        timeOut++
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
        exported = pinExported(gpioPin)
    }
     ...
```

So now I'm searching for an elegant way to mock/replace somehow the above `pinExported` function within my unit tests to test the logic inside `isGpioPinExported` because the function `pinExported` is hardware dependent (Raspberry PI).

One solution could be to make the `pinExported` function a parameter of `isGpioPinExported`

So defining a function type like this:

```
type pinExported func(int) int
```

which means I have to define `isGpioPinExported` like this:

```
isGpioPinExported(pinExported pinExported, gpioPin int) bool {
    exported := pinExported(gpioPin)
    for !exported && (timeOut < timeOutForPinExportInMilliseconds) {
    ...
    }
    ..
}
```

Now I can write my unit test and define a mock/fake `pinExported` without a problem. So far so good. But I have about five or six of such functions which means it would result in putting five or six supplemental parameters to a function like `isGpioPinExported` which is simply wrong. Apart from that the question is where can I define the default implementation which are used if this is not running under test?

Comment: You can declare an interface that lists the functions you want to mock as its methods and have the dependant code depend on that interface instead of the individual functions, then you need to only pass one param instead of 5-6. You can declare a struct type, have `isGpioPinExported` be a method on that struct type, and have the functions that you want to mock be individual fields of that struct type, then you don't have to pass them around when calling the method. Or you can keep doing what you're doing and use testhooks...

Comment: ... as an example: testhook [declaration](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5bd7e9c54f946eec95d32762e7e9e1222504bfc1/src/net/hook.go#L14), testhook ["placement"](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e64241216dd141589144a07f7f68acd64dc108fe/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go#L58), and testhook [setup/teardown](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/9f513254ae92e2a62c3197cf16f7f22a8ca2879a/src/net/dial_test.go#L463-L475)

Comment: @mkopriva See my answer. Thanks for your thoughts and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the suggestion of mkopriva I have created an interface which looks like this (now with three functions to see how this really works):

```
type Raspberry interface {
    isPinExported(gpioPin int) bool
    valueExist(gpioPin int) bool
    directionExist(gpioPin int) bool
}
```

Furthermore defined a structure to make the implementation for real hardware (Raspberry):

```
type Rasberry3Plus struct {
}

func (raspberry Rasberry3Plus) valueExist(gpioPin int) bool {
    pinPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d/value", sysClassGPIOPin, gpioPin)
    if file, err := os.Stat(pinPath); err == nil && len(file.Name()) > 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func (raspberry Rasberry3Plus) directionExist(gpioPin int) bool {
    pinPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d/direction", sysClassGPIOPin, gpioPin)
    if file, err := os.Stat(pinPath); err == nil && len(file.Name()) > 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func (raspberry Rasberry3Plus) isPinExported(gpioPin int) bool {
    pinPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", sysClassGPIOPin, gpioPin)
    if file, err := os.Stat(pinPath); err == nil && len(file.Name()) > 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

and the function `IsGpioPinExported` which uses the above functions looks now like this (This is just an example implementation to see how the mocking testing works):

```
func IsGpioPinExported(raspberry Raspberry, gpioPin int) bool {
    pinExported := raspberry.isPinExported(gpioPin)
    valueExist := raspberry.valueExist(gpioPin)
    directionExist := raspberry.directionExist(gpioPin)

    return valueExist && directionExist && pinExported
}
```

So now the tests look like this. First I have to define a type (btw: I have decided to go with Mock):

```
import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
    "testing"
)

type mockRaspberry struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (raspMock mockRaspberry) isPinExported(gpioPin int) bool {
    args := raspMock.Called(gpioPin)
    return args.Bool(0)
}
func (raspMock mockRaspberry) valueExist(gpioPin int) bool {
    args := raspMock.Called(gpioPin)
    return args.Bool(0)
}
func (raspMock mockRaspberry) directionExist(gpioPin int) bool {
    args := raspMock.Called(gpioPin)
    return args.Bool(0)
}

func Test_ValueTrue_DirectionExistTrue(t *testing.T) {
    testObj := new(mockRaspberry)

    testObj.On("isPinExported", 5).Return(false)
    testObj.On("valueExist", 5).Return(true)
    testObj.On("directionExist", 5).Return(true)

    exported := IsGpioPinExported(testObj, 5)
    assert.Equal(t, false, exported)
}
```

And now it is simple to test the loigic in function `IsGpioPinExported` with the appropriate mocked functions with wished result. And finally the main program looks like this:

```
func main() {
    rasberry3Plus := gpio.Rasberry3Plus{}
    gpio.IsGpioPinExported(rasberry3Plus, 23)
}
```